# Fresh install docker whezzy with php56 does not run out of the box

Tags: php

I am now trying to use `php5.6` in the Debian 7(Wheezy). By this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/694385/how-to-upgrade-php-5-4-to-php-5-6-on-debian-gnu-linux-7-wheezy)

Here is my `DockerFile`

```
FROM debian:7

RUN echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg -O- | apt-key add -

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc apache2 \
    php5-sybase php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-fpm
RUN apt-get install -y nano curl


#RUN mkdir /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN rm /var/www/index.html

#COPY application ./application
COPY assets ./assets
COPY phpStorm-CC-Helpers-master ./phpStorm-CC-Helpers-master
COPY pushnotification ./pushnotification
#COPY system ./system
COPY uploads ./uploads
COPY web.config .
COPY index.php .

RUN a2enmod php5
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

And here is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: gen365-cms
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=root
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=root
    volumes:
      - "./application:/var/www/application"
      - "./system:/var/www/system"
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
```

The `repository` works perfectly fine. They do the great job.

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.32-1~dotdeb+7.1 (cli) (built: Nov  2 2017 18:55:13)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

As far as I know. `php5` normally works out of the box. I confirm I had install `libapache2-mod-php5` according to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/665617/php-5-6-5-wont-work-very-well)

**Problem:**

It does not work. `php` does not run at all.

Comment: is `php` in your $PATH variable?

Comment: @mquinn Thank you for your attention. I really appreciate your response. With `Docker` I love this tool and in the same time I also hate its caching.
My colleague sit by here. Be able to run it normally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caching problem in the docker image.